# What does python attribute error 'str' object has no attribute mean?

Tags: python, codeskulptor

I am working on a beginner python project on CodeSkulptor to build the game blackjack. In my code for Blackjack, I am receiving this error when I iterate through the Hit handler: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_rank'. What 'str' object is this referring to?

Error appears in the this section, found in the Hand class, get_value attribute appears at this line  : **for card in self.hand:
value += VALUES[card.get_rank()]**

```
# Mini-project #6 - Blackjack
#Jolen Martinez

import simplegui
import random

# load card sprite - 936x384 - source: jfitz.com
CARD_SIZE = (72, 96)
CARD_CENTER = (36, 48)
card_images = simplegui.load_image("http://storage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/cards_jfitz.png")

CARD_BACK_SIZE = (72, 96)
CARD_BACK_CENTER = (36, 48)
card_back = simplegui.load_image("http://storage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/card_jfitz_back.png")    

# initialize some useful global variables
in_play = False
outcome = ""
score = 0

# define globals for cards
SUITS = ('C', 'S', 'H', 'D')
RANKS = ('A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K')
VALUES = {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, 'T':10, 'J':10, 'Q':10, 'K':10}
DECK = []
PLAYER_HAND = []
DEALER_HAND = []

# define card class
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        if (suit in SUITS) and (rank in RANKS):
            self.suit = suit
            self.rank = rank
        else:
            self.suit = None
            self.rank = None
            print "Invalid card: ", suit, rank

    def __str__(self):
        return self.suit + self.rank

    def get_suit(self):
        return self.suit

    def get_rank(self):
        return self.rank

    def draw(self, canvas, pos):
        card_loc = (CARD_CENTER[0] + CARD_SIZE[0] * RANKS.index(self.rank), 
                    CARD_CENTER[1] + CARD_SIZE[1] * SUITS.index(self.suit))
        canvas.draw_image(card_images, card_loc, CARD_SIZE, [pos[0] + CARD_CENTER[0], pos[1] + CARD_CENTER[1]], CARD_SIZE)

# define hand class
class Hand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []
       # create Hand object

    def __str__(self):
        handstr = 'Hand contains: '
        for x in self.hand:
            handstr = handstr + str(x) + ' '
        return handstr  # return a string representation of a hand

    def add_card(self, card):
        self.hand.append(card)
        # add a card object to a hand

    def get_value(self):
        # count aces as 1, if the hand has an ace, then add 10 to hand value if it doesn't bust
        value = 0
        **for card in self.hand:
            value += VALUES[card.get_rank()]**
        for card in self.hand:
            if card.get_rank == "A":
                if value + 10 <= 21:
                    return value + 10
        return value
   
    def draw(self, canvas, pos):
        pass    # draw a hand on the canvas, use the draw method for cards
 
        
# define deck class 
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = ['CA', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'CT', 'CJ', 'CQ', 'CK',
                     'SA', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8', 'S9', 'ST', 'SJ', 'SQ', 'SK',
                     'HA', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'H7', 'H8', 'H9', 'HT', 'HJ', 'HQ', 'HK',
                     'DA', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7', 'D8', 'D9', 'DT', 'DJ', 'DQ', 'DK']
    def shuffle(self):
        # shuffle the deck 
        return random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def deal_card(self):
        return self.deck.pop()
    
    def __str__(self):
        deckstr = 'Deck contains: '
        for x in self.deck:
            deckstr = deckstr + str(x) + " "
        return deckstr  # return a string representation of a hand
    # return a string representing the deck

#define event handlers for buttons
def deal():
    global outcome, in_play, DECK, PLAYER_HAND, DEALER_HAND
    DECK = Deck()
    DECK.shuffle()
    print str(DECK)
    PLAYER_HAND = Hand()
    DEALER_HAND = Hand()
    PLAYER_HAND.add_card(DECK.deal_card())
    PLAYER_HAND.add_card(DECK.deal_card())
    DEALER_HAND.add_card(DECK.deal_card())
    DEALER_HAND.add_card(DECK.deal_card())
    print str(PLAYER_HAND)
    print str(DEALER_HAND)
    
    in_play = True
   

def hit():
    global in_play
    if in_play:
        if PLAYER_HAND.get_value() <= 21:
            PLAYER_HAND.add_card(DECK.deal_card())
        if PLAYER_HAND.get_value() > 21:
            in_play = False
            

 
    # if the hand is in play, hit the player
   
    # if busted, assign a message to outcome, update in_play and score
       
def stand():
    global in_play
    if in_play:
        while DEALER_HAND.get_value() <= 17:
            DEALER_HAND.add_card(DECK.deal_card())
        in_play = False
        if DEALER_HAND.get_value() > 21:
            print "Dealer busted, Player Wins!"
        elif DEALER_HAND.get_value() >= PLAYER_HAND.get_value:
            print "Player Loses"
        else:
            print "Player Wins!"
    
   
    # if hand is in play, repeatedly hit dealer until his hand has value 17 or more

    # assign a message to outcome, update in_play and score

# draw handler    
def draw(canvas):
    # test to make sure that card.draw works, replace with your code below
    
    card = Card("S", "A")
    card.draw(canvas, [300, 300])


# initialization frame
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Blackjack", 600, 600)
frame.set_canvas_background("Green")

#create buttons and canvas callback
frame.add_button("Deal", deal, 200)
frame.add_button("Hit",  hit, 200)
frame.add_button("Stand", stand, 200)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)


# get things rolling
deal()
frame.start()
```

Comment: the error appears here:     **for card in self.hand:
            value += VALUES[card.get_rank()]**

Comment: `card` is a string, not a `Card` object (because that's what is returned by `Deck.deal_card`). A string doesn't have a `get_rank` method.

Comment: Thanks for asking a question. You should consider replacing the code in your question with a minimal example that reproduces your issue. This will help others quickly understand your issue.

Comment: @larsks , thank you for your comment. how can I go about making card into a Card object and not a string?

Comment: @JohnIngram apologies, I will do so in the next post, thank you

Comment: I tried changing the Deck.deal_card, but it also says that the list doesn't have this attribute. how do I have it recognize a get_rank method?

Answer (score 0):

Your `deal_card()` function returns a string, get from

```
self.deck = ['CA', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'CT', 'CJ', 'CQ', 'CK',
             'SA', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8', 'S9', 'ST', 'SJ', 'SQ', 'SK',
             'HA', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'H7', 'H8', 'H9', 'HT', 'HJ', 'HQ', 'HK',
             'DA', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7', 'D8', 'D9', 'DT', 'DJ', 'DQ', 'DK']
```

You need to do something like this:

```
def deal_card(self):
    suit, rank = self.deck.pop()

    return Card(suit, rank)
```

That gets a string from `deck`, split in one character for suit and one character for rank, build a `Card` object with these parameters, and then returns this `Card` object.

Your code with my adaptation:
https://py2.codeskulptor.org/#user48_nw49jEMU2m_0.py